# know udp packet size with poll select or epoll

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I know that to find out the size of the udp packet before reading you can issue this syscall to the kernel:

```
ioctl(s,FIONREAD,&num_bytes);
```

But, can I find out the same with one of the following syscalls ?

```
poll()
select()
epoll()
```

The key is to know the size of the datagram before reading it, to allocate space for the buffer.
This is for linux only, in C.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `recvfrom` has a `MSG_PEEK` flag you can use to query the number of bytes in the packet (and preview its content without removing it from the queue), which would be a lot more portable than ugly `ioctl` solutions... :-)

Comment: Max UDP datagram size is 64K, but do you ever get UDP messages larger then 1472 bytes? What protocol is that?

Comment: @R. thanks R, good tip. What I was looking is to save on syscalls, if some of the mentioned 3 syscalls could give me the size of the available  packet (besides notifying me that there is data available on the descriptor to be read), that would be very helpful to speed up the code (because I have to use one of the above 3 anyway when the application is waiting for input)

Comment: They can't. My post was purely an aside, which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @R. Ok, I got it. closing this question. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplexing syscalls like [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or `select` are expecting a set of conditions to watch (like input is available on fd #5, output is possible on fd #7) and tell you which file descriptors are readable (and which ones are writable, etc.). Once you know which file descriptor can be read, you can use your `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &numbytes)` on that readable file descriptor `fd`.  So you should use both `poll` and then `FIONREAD`  ...

Comment: I'm fairly sure that with UDP you can expect a single packet to be received with a single `read` or `recv` call, providing your buffer is big enough. (obviously this is not true for TCP)

Comment: That is correct. The sockets interface will only return full packets, not fragments.

Comment: I thought that routers are permitted to fragment UDP packet.. I removed that last sentence..

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Routers can fragment packets as long as the "Dont Fragment" bit is not set. If the packet gets Fragmented and I only receive 4/5 of the fragmented packet then you won't see the packet.